# Fragment shared element transition with add() instead of replace()?

Tags: android, shared-element-transition, fragment-transitions

I am trying to make a shared element transition between fragments, everything works fine when using `replace()` to add the second fragment, however in the codebase `add()` is used a lot, but when using that, *transition just skips to end values*

**Is it possible to have the transition between added fragments?**
Thanks

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity())
        .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));

    FragmentB secondFragment = new FragmentB();
    secondFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity())
        .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, secondFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .addSharedElement(imageView, imageView.getTransitionName())
        .commit();
}
```

Comment: The other fragment you are using is a child fragment ?

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() 
                .addSharedElement(myImage, "mytransition") 
                .add(R.id.recycler_view_container, myFragment2) 
                .hide(myFragment1)  
                 commit();
```

worked for me

Answer (score 4):

since the system isnt going through the onPause from the first fragment its not going to happen. becuase when you add a new fragment, the new fragment comes on the top of the old fragment.

but you can fake it though you will have more code !

there is a sample below:

https://github.com/Kisty/FragmentTransitionExample

and a video not compeletely related but helps you to get the idea:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA

Comment: This hack seems to work for ImageViews but it is a little complicated if the view is a viewgroup itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try add .detach() method for FragmentTransaction.

```
    FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager ();
    Fragment currentFragment = manager.findFragmentById (CONTAINER_ID); 
    int intoContainerId = currentFragment.getId ();
    manager.beginTransaction ()
            .setTransition (FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .addSharedElement(view, transitionName)
            .addToBackStack (withTag)
            .detach(currentFragment)
            .add(intoContainerId, newFragment, withTag)
            .commit();
```

Comment: this makes the view in background go from UI, which destroys the whole purpose of adding the fragment instead of replacing it in first place.